# After crawling a website, I have non-perl files with a .pl extension

Tags: perl

I have a static website I downloaded. Among the usual `.css`, `.js` and `.html` files there is a `.pl` file with the following contents:

[image]

I had to upload a screenshot because the file contents didn't display correctly when I copied and pasted them here. I understand it's a Perl file but can anyone tell me what purpose it has?

Comment: .pl is usually a perl file, but this happens to be a .gif image

Comment: what did you use to download the website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell from the [magic byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) in that file that it's a GIF file. GIF98a is a version of a gif file.

So what almost certainly happened is

- Someone created a web server
- That server is running in CGI mode.
- They have a perl script (which is normally `.pl` suffix)
- That perl script is serving up files.
- That perl script did not set [`Content-Disposition` header properly](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) so your browser doesn't know what to save it as.
- Your browser defaulted the save-name to the name of the cgi script, or you accepted that manually.
- It served you a `.gif` file, which you downloaded to that location.